# c# method looks very redundant what can i do to fix it design pattern , method?

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I have this method in C# that looks like I should really refactor it .  Should I use a design pattern ?   Too much repetition is what I see NOW and especially as MORE conditional if statements get added

Change to a method?

```
public void CreateOrUpdateReportDefinition(ReportGroupSubReport reportGroupSubReport, bool isNew, int report)
    {

        if (report == 1)
        {
            var entity = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.GetById(reportGroupSubReport.Id) ?? new ReportDefinition();
            if (isNew)
                entity.SetNew();

            _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);
        }
        else if (report == 2)
        {
            var entity = _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.GetById(reportGroupSubReport.Id) ?? new TraxReport();

            if (isNew)
                entity.SetNew();

            _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);

        }


        Mapper.Map(reportGroupSubReport, entity);
        _envyUnitOfWork.Commit();


    }
```

Comment: I think this question would fit better here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually even that code does not work as  `Mapper.Map(reportGroupSubReport, entity);`   has a problem with entity not existing in current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I would do is to put every single conditional behavior into separate method. To avoid repetition you could use the template method pattern. You should also declare your report variable before all if statements so that it would be accessible for the Mapper.Map().

Edit:
Ok, so assuming that both _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports and _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions share some common generic interface (which I named Repository in code) defining GetById and InsertOrUpdate methods, you do not need to use any design patterns - simple generic method will do the job. Here is example of the code:

```
    private void createOrUpdateReportDefinition<Report>(ReportGroupSubReport reportGroupSubReport, bool isNew, Repository<Report> repository/*, Action<Report> insertOrUpdate*/) where Report : new()
    {
        var entity = repository.GetById(reportGroupSubReport.Id) ?? new Report();
        if (isNew)
            entity.SetNew();
        repository.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);//insertOrUpdate(entity, true);            
        Mapper.Map(reportGroupSubReport, entity);
        _envyUnitOfWork.Commit();
    }


    public void CreateOrUpdateReportDefinition(ReportGroupSubReport reportGroupSubReport, bool isNew, int report)
    {

        if (report == 1)
        {
            createOrUpdateReportDefinition(reportGroupSubReport, isNew, _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions/*, _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.InsertOrUpdate*/);
        }
        else if (report == 2)
        {
            createOrUpdateReportDefinition(reportGroupSubReport, isNew, _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports/*, _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.InsertOrUpdate*/);
        }

    }
```

Please take under consideration this code is dealing only with one issue in your code which was the code duplication, there are still few things you could improve like removing `int report` parameter from the method either by dividing it into few methods or at least by replacing it with some enum with meaningful name. I would also suggest the same (dividing the methods) for the `bool isNew` parameter, since using it means your function doesn't do one thing only which is against single responsibility principle from SOLID - you can read more about it [here.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior)

Comment: An example of what you propose?

Comment: What type exactly    _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports and _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions are?

Comment: `IRepository<TraxReport> TraxReports { get; set; } `    then  implementation    `public IRepository<TraxReport> TraxReports { get; set; } `

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that the way another group of developers wrote the repository pattern and Unit of work pattern is "correct" or not ,  but I cannot do  `repository.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);`   I would have to do `_envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);`  which seems to be tightly coupled doesn't it?

Comment: EnvyUnitofWork class then contains   `public IRepository<TraxReport> TraxReports { get; set; } `

Comment: I could pass in `IEnvyUnitOfWork repository`   but then I still end up with a problem in which I need to do this `var entity = repository.TraxReports.GetById(reportGroupSubReport.Id) ?? new TraxReport();`    - since  repository is not enough

Comment: Check out the changed code in the answer (commented part). Using delegates doesn't seem to me to be the cleanest solution, but it should work and I can't come up with anything better than that at the moment :)

Answer (score -2):

The following refactoring pattern might give you some clues as to how you could manage the proliferating conditional problem: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Edit: The easiest way to do this would be defining an Interface that both TraxReports and ReportDefinition implement that has a InsertOrUpdate method.

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of the link here that specifically answer the question...

Comment: No. The link is enough to suggest some further reading that may help to find a suitable answer.

Comment: So you're saying your link only answer isn't even an answer - delete it then and put it as a comment I'm future

Comment: No. What I was saying was that my answer pointed the questioner to information on a design pattern that's suitable for managing conditional logic and that, IMHO, addresses the questioners' specific concerns regarding repetitive code and proliferation of the conditions. Whether that pattern is the most suitable answer for them is not up to me. What I was also saying was I felt no need to copy the content. Personally, I see no value in that. If none of this falls within the ethos of SO then I apologise.

Comment: I'm sure your aware it's customary in StackOverflow answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer, the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. In this case the link you provided **ISN'T EVEN C#** !!! Most importantly, if your link were to ever break, your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future.

Comment: For more information on posting links please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers